Why instances are compatible even if their class constructors are not compatible?
In the following example, the constructors are not compatible but their instances are compatible. Why?
class Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  constructor(name: string, age: number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}

class Employee {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  salary: number;
  constructor(name: string, age: number, salary: number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.salary = salary;
  }
}

const pCtor: typeof Person = Employee; // error, constructors are not compatible
const p: Person = new Employee("", 0, 0); // but the instances *are* compatible, how is that possible?


The answer is because instances don't have a strongly typed constructor property, specifically because if they did, then inheritance would break badly in cases like this example here; JS allows constructors of subclasses to be incompatible with those of superclasses, and it would be a nightmare if class hierarchies no longer represented type hierarchies. This is all laid out in ms/TS#3841. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz: Yes, and thank you for trying to understand my previous question. I didn't know that it was not formulated correctly.

See microsoft/TypeScript#3841 for an authoritative answer to this question. The constructor property of class instances are not very strongly typed in TypeScript.  It is just given the Function type, and so the type named Employee is assignable to the type named Person, as the constructor property of each do not conflict.

But why isn't p.constructor more strongly typed? See this comment in microsoft/TypeScript#3841.
It is strongly desirable in TypeScript for extending classes to also extend their instances. That is, you want class Foo extends Bar { ⋯ } to imply that Foo extends Bar, so that class hierarchies are also type hierarchies.  Otherwise you could write const bar: Bar = new Foo() and get an error, and nobody wants that; it would break so much real world code as to make Typescript a nightmare to use.
But, JavaScript also allows constructors of subclasses to be incompatible with those of their superclasses. This is also very desirable, especially since some built-in JavaScript class hierarchies work this way.  So we want to allow this:
class Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  constructor(name: string, age: number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}

class Employee extends Person {
  salary: number;
  constructor(name: string, age: number, salary: number) {
    super(name, age);
    this.salary = salary;
  }
}

const pCtor: typeof Person = Employee; // error, constructors are not compatible
const p: Person = new Employee("", 0, 0); // no error, instances are compatible

And that means that p.constructor cannot be of type typeof Person without breaking the above code, which we don't want to do.  It could be that p.constructor is stronger than Function, like perhaps, just the static members of Person, but right now that's not how it works. And it doesn't affect the example here anyway.

Finally, note that your code example is identical to this from the type system's point of view. They are structurally unchanged, even though p instanceof Person will be different.  You don't need an extends clause for types to be compatible. So even in the case that Employee looks like
class Employee {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  salary: number;
  constructor(name: string, age: number, salary: number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.salary = salary;
  }
}

there's no change in TypeScript's behavior.  An Employee's constructor property is of type Function, and thus every Employee is structurally compatible with  Person.
Playground link to code

Type A being compatible with Type B tells you that an instance of Type A can be used as an instance type B. That means the instance has to support all operations that may be performed on the other type (that is, have the necessary properties & methods).
Employee supports every operation that you may perform on a Person, therefore it is assignable to a Person-variable.
Incompatible constructors do not change that, because that is not an operation that the instances of the class must allow. You do not call a constructor on a 'Person' or 'Employee' object.
Also note that even without the constructor-issue, the types would not be the same: Person-instances could not be assigned to Employee-typed-variables, because Employee has the salary-field, and Person does not. Using a person where an employee is expected might result in an error that TypeScript protects you from, but using an employee as a person does not harbour this danger.

I realize that you can access a constructor from an instances prototype in javascript, so this is not 100% sound. But I guess Typescript favored the common case (inheritance with incompatible constructors) over the weird case (hacking around in prototype).

My answer is written from a perspective of "This behaviour is what I would expect" and not a "Here is what the spec says". I think the latter answer would be interesting, but I cannot help with that.
